# Too big d3.event.scale zoom handling

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, javafx, zooming

I've implemented the [Force Directed Graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) from the d3.js Demo Page. I'd like to enable zooming and dragging on the Graph. So far best I could get was from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/QMKm3/) zooming and translating works, but the d3.event.scale ratio is too big. Just some sample output:

```
Base: translate: 0,0, scale: 1.0000000000000002    
1 zoom in: translate: -276691.7368930365,-243364.72096474364, scale: 776.0468820533237
2 zoom in: translate: -215002451.4426526,-189105797.62743115, scale: 602248.7631446852
3 zoom in: translate: -166852258767.62857,-146755207991.69574, scale: 467373274.8589036
4 zoom in: translate: -129485175456864.23,-113888921830407.19, scale: 362703572709.30316
Back to base: translate: 0,0, scale: 1.0000000000000004
1 zoom out: translate: 356.53997624595127,313.59538526954816, scale: 0.0012885819441141556
2 zoom out: translate: 356.9994072216967,313.999478620764, scale: 0.000001660443426697016
3 zoom out: translate: 356.99999923615655,313.99999932816013, scale: 2.13961741886481e-9
4 zoom out: translate: 356.9999999990157,313.9999999991343, scale: 2.757072373261327e-12
```

If you zoom in, it's way to big and basically your whole screen is filled. If you zoom out you can't see anything. How can I change the d3.event.scale ratio to be smaller? So far this code has to do with zooming / translating:

```
var width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth,
                window.innerWidth || 0);
var height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight,
                window.innerHeight || 0);
//Define width & height as big as window

var svg = d3.select("body").attr('width', width).attr('height',
                height).attr("pointer-events", "all").append("svg").append(
                "g").call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", zoom)).append("g");
//Add svg tag to body

svg.append('rect').attr('width', width).attr('height', height)
                .attr('fill', 'white');

function zoom() {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
        + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    java.getData("translate: " + d3.event.translate + ", scale: "
                    + d3.event.scale);
}
```

At this point I'm not sure if it's worth mentioning, but under the `<g></g>` tag I create a group to store a circle and a label

```
var gnodes = svg.selectAll('g.gnode').data(graph.nodes).enter()
                    .append('g').classed('gnode', true);
//Create the groups under svg
```

Since I'm new to JavaScript I might be missing the point where the zoom behaviour goes wrong, if additional snippets are needed, let me know.

Note: `java.getData(String data);` is a method from a "bridge class" to connect the JavaScript page with the JavaFX WebView and Java Code.

Edit:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, width])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, height])
    .range([height, 0]);        

var svg = d3.select("body").attr('width', width).attr('height',
    height).attr("pointer-events", "all").append("svg").append(
    "g").call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom)).append("g");
//Add svg tag to body
```

Now I have this output:

```
1 zoom in: translate: -798,-1337, scale: 8
Normal: translate: 0,0, scale: 1
```

Zooming in is now limited to scale 8. 1 mouse wheel trigger scales to 8, content readable, but still too big, scale < 1 not possible. Is it possible to define better scaling?
Tried this: `scaleExtent([1, 2, 4, 8])` and `scaleExtent([.5, 1, 2, 4, 8])` first one scales 1 or 2, second one scales 0.5 or 1. Can't I define more than 2 ratios?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/QMKm3/884/) of my work so far, doesn't eveb draw the svg in the browser, but does in fx, sadly doesn't has a debugger.

Comment: I have a hunch that if the http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/QMKm3/ works fine on your browser ... then most likely some other code is interfering to change the scale to such big values :(

Comment: Well I open the demo in my Browser (IE) and running my JS in a JavaFX WebView, there is still hope ^^

Comment: Hmm...may be the issue with webview...your code is identical to the fiddle, don't see any reason for this behavior.
May be you can tag this question to javafx may be some expert may give you an answer. It appears to be a web view issue.

Comment: I can't see the links between the nodes in the fiddle on my browser, maybe it's a IE fault or I really have some strange code.

Comment: well the reason y you not seeing the link is beacuse stroke not added in the css http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/QMKm3/838/

Comment: I see your point there x)

Comment: @Cyril was right, it seems to be a JavaFX WebView issue.